# Lock table in Postgres to allow reading by other transactions, but disallow writing

Tags: django, postgresql, locking

I'm developing a Django application. There's a functionality where I want to change the database state by reading from, making calculations, and inserting to many tables. This is an atomic procedure, and it can't be only "single-threaded", because the resulting state depends on the order, in which such procedures are executed.

For that I use Celery with a single worker. I thought about SERIALIZED isolation level in Postgres, until I had read:

> Serializable transactions is guaranteed to produce the same effect as running them one at a time in **some** order

But I don't need *some*, I need the *exact* order, that's why I chose the message queue.

During the procedure I want to disallow writing to the tables I operate on completely, but still allow reading. What least restrictive LOCK mode suits my case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you question right, you want:

```
lock table_name in exclusive mode;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

> EXCLUSIVE
>
> Conflicts with the ROW SHARE, ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE,
>   SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock
>   modes. This mode allows only concurrent ACCESS SHARE locks, i.e., only
>   reads from the table can proceed in parallel with a transaction
>   holding this lock mode.

Other sessions will read table in state it was before you started the transaction and locked the table. Attempt to write to a table will put session in waiting for your transaction to complete

Comment: Thank you. I've read that documentation and now think that SHARE is less restrictive.

Comment: how to restrict even read? Any idea guys?

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari
I think what you're looking for is `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`.